# Annotation @Field of spring-data-elasticsearch not working

Tags: spring, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm tryng to use @Field annotation on a property of a entity like this :

```
@Field(index=FieldIndex.no ,  type  = FieldType.Object , store = false)
private MyObject miobject;
```

but when the entity is indexed on ElasticSearch property "miobject" is also indexed.... Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
@Field(index=FieldIndex.not_analyzed,  type  = FieldType.Object , store = false)
```